# Why does loading the libc shared library have "'LibraryLoader' object is not callable" error?

Tags: python, linux, ctypes, libc, dynamic-loading

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface

> the ctypes module can load C functions from shared libraries/DLLs
>   on-the-fly and translate simple data types automatically between
>   Python and C semantics as follows:
>
> ```
> import ctypes
> libc = ctypes.CDLL( '/lib/libc.so.6' )   # under Linux/Unix
> t = libc.time(None)                      # equivalent C code: t = time(NULL)
> print t
> ```

On Lubuntu 18.04

```
$ whereis libc
libc: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so /usr/share/man/man7/libc.7.gz

$ locate libc.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so

$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 298 Apr 16 16:14 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
```

I was wondering why loading the libc shared library  has "'LibraryLoader' object is not callable" error?

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.5

$ python3

>>> import ctypes
>>> libc=ctypes.cdll("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'LibraryLoader' object is not callable


>>> libc=ctypes.cdll("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'LibraryLoader' object is not callable


>>> libc=ctypes.cdll("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'LibraryLoader' object is not callable
```

See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449107/what-differences-and-relations-are-between-the-various-libc-so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing lower case `cdll` (which is a [`LibraryLoader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.LibraryLoader)) with upper case [`CDLL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.CDLL), which is the constructor for shared libraries.

This code will work as expected:

```
libc = ctypes.CDLL("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6")
```

Comment: Wouldn’t it be better to load `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`? Otherwise the Python script will need the C library development packages at run-time...

Comment: @StephenKitt I think that's outside of the scope of the question. It's about how to load a library correctly, not which one is the best.

Comment: Agreed; I was just trying to reduce the risk of copy-pasta ;-) (and it would make the answer correspond to the example which started all this).

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between  a LibraryLoader (e.g. `cdll`) and the constructor for shared libraries (e.g. `CDLL`)? Can they both   do the same thing?

Comment: @Tim I'm not sure what to say to that. It's all explained in the documentation, so I can really only repeat the information from there: A LibraryLoader is an object that lets you load libraries through attribute access. `CDLL` (along with `WinDLL` and the others) is the class of those loaded libraries. Basically, `cdll.foo == CDLL('foo')`, `windll.foo == WinDLL('foo')`, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Do we need to create `cdll.foo` first? If yes, is it done by `cdll.LoadLibrary("foo")`?

Comment: @Tim You don't need to create it first. The whole point of the LibraryLoader is that it creates the library for you when you access it. And no, `cdll.LoadLibrary("foo")` doesn't create `cdll.foo`. As [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.LibraryLoader.LoadLibrary) states, the `LoadLibrary` method always creates a new instance, whereas `cdll.foo` will always be the *same* instance.

Comment: Thanks. I am still too slow to understand your comment. I thought it would be better to create a new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838633/how-is-the-attribute-of-the-loader-instance-cdll-created, to avoid the length of comments.

Comment: @Aran-Fey  I am not sure how `cdll.foo` is assigned a value to. Could you look again at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838633/how-is-the-attribute-of-the-loader-instance-cdll-created/?

Comment: @StephenKitt  Thanks. I'd appreciate again if you could take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838633/how-is-the-attribute-of-the-loader-instance-cdll-created/50840871