# How can `CDLL()` find a file to load, with only file basename?

Tags: python, linux, ctypes, libc, dynamic-loading

On Lubuntu 18.04

```
$ python3
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")
>>> libc.printf
<_FuncPtr object at 0x7f10caf0d9a8>
```

I didn't specify path for libc.so.6, so how can `CDLL()` find its file to load?

Originated from [Why does loading the libc shared library have "'LibraryLoader' object is not callable" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798907/why-does-loading-the-libc-shared-library-have-libraryloader-object-is-not-cal#50798907)

Answer (score 2):

That is because `CDLL` (or `LibraryLoader` or anything else from from [[Python]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) - and things can be expanded even more) uses the "native library loading system" in order to deal with library (searching and) loading (including dependencies). 
On *Ux* systems, that is typically accomplished by the **dynamic linker/loader**.

Now, I assume that you're wondering why e.g. ***"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6"*** is found, even though ***"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"*** is **not** in ***${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}***.

From [[man7]: LD.SO(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html):

> The program **ld.so** handles a.out binaries, a format used long ago; **ld-linux.so*** (*/lib/ld-linux.so.1* for libc5, */lib/ld-linux.so.2* for glibc2) handles ELF, which everybody has been using for years now. Otherwise, both have the same behavior, and use the same support files and programs as [ldd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html), [ldconfig(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html), and ***/etc/ld.so.conf***.

From [[man7]: LD(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html):

> The linker uses the following search paths to locate required shared libraries:
>        ...
>       8. For a native linker on an ELF system, if the file ***/etc/ld.so.conf*** exists, the list of directories found in that file.

Example on my *VM*:

> ```
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow]> uname -a
> Linux cfati-ubtu16x64-0 4.13.0-43-generic #48~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 17 12:56:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow]> which ls
> /bin/ls
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow]> file /bin/ls
> /bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=d0bc0fb9b3f60f72bbad3c5a1d24c9e2a1fde775, stripped
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow]> ldd /bin/ls
>         linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc0e2e1000)
>         libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f64b63d0000)
>         libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f64b6006000)
>         libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f64b5d96000)
>         libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f64b5b92000)
>         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f64b65f2000)
>         libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f64b5975000)
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow]> readelf -d /bin/ls
>
> Dynamic section at offset 0x1de18 contains 25 entries:
>   Tag        Type                         Name/Value
>  0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libselinux.so.1]
>  0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
>  ...
>
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow]> cat /etc/ld.so.conf
> include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
>
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow]> ls -al /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 32 iun  6 17:42 /etc/ld.so.conf.d/00vboxvideo.conf
> -rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 38 nov 24  2014 /etc/ld.so.conf.d/fakeroot-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 44 ian 27  2016 /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 68 apr 15  2016 /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 mar  9 19:43 /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf -> /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 mar  9 19:43 /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf -> /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 56 ian 15 04:49 /etc/ld.so.conf.d/zz_i386-biarch-compat.conf
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 58 ian 15 04:50 /etc/ld.so.conf.d/zz_x32-biarch-compat.conf
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow]> cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
> # Multiarch support
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
> ```

Since it's *libc* related, also check [[SO]: How does ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(None) work? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49878901/how-does-ctypes-cdll-loadlibrarynone-work/49880922#49880922) in order to use the already loaded *libc* version (and avoid possible conflicts), **if** *libc* isn't linked statically.

Comment: Did this answer your question?