# How is the attribute of the loader instance `cdll` created?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shared-libraries, ctypes, dynamic-loading

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#loading-shared-libraries

> Shared libraries can also be loaded by using one of the prefabricated
>   objects, which are instances of the LibraryLoader class, either **by
>   calling the LoadLibrary() method**, or **by retrieving the library as
>   attribute of the loader instance**.

I found an example for the first way [Free the opened ctypes library in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21770419/156458)

I was wondering how to use the second way? In particular, how is the attribute of the loader instance `cdll` created?  My question comes from [Why does loading the libc shared library have "'LibraryLoader' object is not callable" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798907/why-does-loading-the-libc-shared-library-have-libraryloader-object-is-not-cal#comment88680810_50799159)

> The whole point of the LibraryLoader is that it creates the library for you when you access it. And `cdll.LoadLibrary("foo")` doesn't create `cdll.foo`.

Is there something wrong with my experiment? Why does `cdll.libc` never exist?

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> cdll.libc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 418, in __getattr__
    dll = self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libc: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>> cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")
<CDLL 'libc.so.6', handle 7f6afe03a000 at 0x7f6afc1afac8>
>>> cdll.libc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 418, in __getattr__
    dll = self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libc: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>> libc=cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")
>>> cdll.libc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 418, in __getattr__
    dll = self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libc: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>> CDLL("libc.so.6")
<CDLL 'libc.so.6', handle 7f6afe03a000 at 0x7f6afc1af978>
>>> cdll.libc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 418, in __getattr__
    dll = self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libc: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

>>> libc=CDLL("libc.so.6")
>>> cdll.libc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 418, in __getattr__
    dll = self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libc: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>> cdll.__dict__
{'_dlltype': <class 'ctypes.CDLL'>}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example (**what** happens):

> ```
> >>> import sys
> >>> import ctypes
> >>> print("Python {:s} on {:s}".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> >>>
> >>> [item for item in dir(ctypes.windll) if "__" not in item]
> ['LoadLibrary', '_dlltype', 'kernel32']
> >>>
> >>> user32_dll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("user32")
> >>> user32_dll
> <WinDLL 'user32', handle 7ff882810000 at 0x2434399b4e0>
> >>> [item for item in dir(ctypes.windll) if "__" not in item]
> ['LoadLibrary', '_dlltype', 'kernel32']
> >>>
> >>> user32_dll = ctypes.WinDLL("user32")
> >>> user32_dll
> <WinDLL 'user32', handle 7ff882810000 at 0x2434399b4a8>
> >>> [item for item in dir(ctypes.windll) if "__" not in item]
> ['LoadLibrary', '_dlltype', 'kernel32']
> >>>
> >>> user32_dll = ctypes.windll.user32
> >>> user32_dll
> <WinDLL 'user32', handle 7ff882810000 at 0x24343984d68>
> >>> [item for item in dir(ctypes.windll) if "__" not in item]
> ['LoadLibrary', '_dlltype', 'kernel32', 'user32']
> >>>
> >>> ctypes.windll.user32
> <WinDLL 'user32', handle 7ff882810000 at 0x24343984d68>
> >>>
> >>> ctypes.windll.user321
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "c:\install\x64\python\python\3.5\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 421, in __getattr__
>     dll = self._dlltype(name)
>   File "c:\install\x64\python\python\3.5\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 351, in __init__
>     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
> OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
> >>>
> >>> dir(ctypes.windll)
> ['LoadLibrary', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_dlltype', 'kernel32', 'user32']
> ```

**How** it happens - it's all in *"${PYTHON_SRC_DIR}/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py"* 
([[GitHub]: python/cpython - (master) cpython/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py)). I'm pasting code for `cdll` since `windll` (that I used in the example above) is just a wrapper over it (and would require a bit more code):

```
# ...

class CDLL(object):

# ...

class LibraryLoader(object):
    def __init__(self, dlltype):
        self._dlltype = dlltype

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name[0] == '_':
            raise AttributeError(name)
        dll = self._dlltype(name)
        setattr(self, name, dll)  # @TODO - cfati: This is the key for always returning the same instance.
        return dll

# ...

cdll = LibraryLoader(CDLL)

# ...
```

***@EDIT0***:

Hmm, on *Ux* (*Lnx* at least) things aren't so nice:

> ```
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q050838633]> ls
> libcapi.so
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q050838633]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd) python3 -c "import ctypes; ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libcapi.so')"
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q050838633]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd) python3 -c "import ctypes; ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libcapi')"
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 425, in LoadLibrary
>     return self._dlltype(name)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
>     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
> OSError: libcapi: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> ```

That is because apparently (as opposed to [[MSDN]: LoadLibrary function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.140).aspx)), [[man7]: DLOPEN(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) doesn't append the (default) library extension (*.so*) to the file name (if it doesn't contain it already).

*code.c*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 1) {
        printf("Dll name required\n");
        return 1;
    }
    void *handle = dlopen(argv[1], RTLD_NOW);
    if (handle == NULL) {
        printf("Could not load [%s]\n", argv[1]);
        return 2;
    } else {
        printf("Successfully loaded [%s]\n", argv[1]);
        dlclose(handle);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q050838633]> gcc code.c -Wl,-ldl
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q050838633]> ./a.out "libcapi.so"
> Could not load [libcapi.so]
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q050838633]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd) ./a.out "libcapi.so"
> Successfully loaded [libcapi.so]
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q050838633]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd) ./a.out "libcapi"
> Could not load [libcapi]
> ```

So, the *Win* behavior can't be replicated on *Ux* (unfortunately, `.` (*dot*) can't be part of an attribute name, in order to overcome this). Or, maybe the linker could be configured to search for *.so* files implicitly? But that would only solve the problem partially as many libraries look like *libc.so.6* (or *AFAIK*, on *OSX* both *.so* and *.dylib* are *OK*).

Comment: All `cdll.libc` statements raised `OSError` like `ctypes.windll.user321` case in which the `user321` wasn't added in `windll` attributes list. Same thing for `cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")` or `CDLL("libc.so.6")` in these situations (even if loading is successful), the attribute is not added to `cdll` (also covered by my example).

Comment: What is the step missing to add the attribute to `cdll`?

Comment: @Tim Since `cdll.libc` doesn't work, the only way you can make `cdll` have a `libc` attribute is by manually assigning something to that attribute. But why would you want to? `cdll` is a convenience wrapper that makes it easier to load shared libraries. If it doesn't work (like on linux), just avoid it.